# Can I use the Z-Test to calculate Goodness of Fit?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

I have a background population defined by a normal distribution:

$$\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are known.

I'd like to perform a [goodness of fit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) test on an observation to check the likelihood that its been drawn from the same distribution. I've read that you should use Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic, but I'd like to use a [Z-Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test).

Is it ever possible to do this?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To check if an observation is likely to be part of the background distribution.

Comment: Is the variance known? If not, have a look at Student’s t-test.

Comment: The variance is known! I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
For a single observation when the mean and variance of the background population are known,  a [two-tailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-_and_two-tailed_tests) $ Z\ $ test and the chi-squared test will give you identical results.  If $\ X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\ $, then the $\ Z\ $ statistic,
$$
Z\eqdef\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\ ,
$$
follows a standard normal distribution and the $\ \chi^2\ $ statistic
$$
\chi^2\eqdef Z^2
$$
follows a chi-squared distribition with one degree of freedom.  If your observed value of $\ X\ $ gives you a value of $\ z\ $ for your $\ Z\ $ statistic, then the $\ p$-value for the two-tailed $\ Z\ $ test is given by
\begin{align}
p&=P(Z\le-|z|)+P(Z\ge|z|)\\
&=2P(Z\ge|z|)\\
&=2\big(1-\mathcal{N}(0,1)(|z|)\big)\ ,
\end{align}
and the $\ p$-value for the chi-squared test is given by
\begin{align}
p&=P\big(\chi^2\ge z^2\big)\\
&=1-\chi_1^2\big(z^2\big)\ .
\end{align}
However, since $\ Z^2\ge z^2\ $ if and only if either $\ Z\le-|z|\ $ or $\ Z\ge|z|\ $, then
\begin{align}
P\big(\chi^2\ge z^2\big)&=P\big(Z^2\ge z^2\big)\\
&=P(Z\le-|z|)+P(Z\ge|z|)\ ,
\end{align}
and it follows that the two $\ p$-values are identical.  In these circumstances, therefore, the two tests are completely equivalent.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thankyou! I've updated the question to provide the variance instead.

Comment: +1 The key point here is that $Z^2\ge z^2$,  associated with a one-tailed $\chi^2$ test, is equivalent to  $(Z \le -|z|) \cup (Z \ge |z|)$, associated with a two-tailed $Z$ test